# CSS animation won't start

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So , I'm doing this car display gallery and I want to use CSS animation.

Using only Firefox for now , and the animation does work when I set the class of the "img" manually for animating to the Left :
HTML:

```
<img src="test3.jpg" id="Position2" class="Pos2ForLeft">
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes Pos2Pos1 {
0% {left: 450; top: 200; width: 400; height:300;}
100%  {left: 200; top: 250; width: 200; height:150;}
}     

.Pos2ForLeft {
position:absolute; left: 450; top: 200; width: 400; height:300;
animation-name: Pos2Pos1;animation-play-state:running;
animation-duration:1s; animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

So when I code it manually , the animation runs and then stops , just like I want it to. But when I start with a standart CSS class and want to switch to the one with the animation , nothing happens:

```
document.getElementById("Position"+i).class = "Pos"+positionsBefore[i]+"ForLeft";
alert(document.getElementById("Position"+i).class)
```

Please ignore loop and variables.I get alerted that the class is changed to the one I want , but nothing happens. Is there something I need to trigger , what's happening?

Comment: any console errors in browser?

Comment: 1. Add units to the position and dimension values in @keyframes, 2. use `.className = 'foo'` or `.classList.add('foo')`: http://jsfiddle.net/j3hboauw/1/

Answer (score 0):

An element in JavaScript won't respond to the 'class' property. The correct property is className. So the code would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("Position"+i).className = "Pos"+positionsBefore[i]+"ForLeft";
```

Comment: Good to hear betastate that that worked for you. Also, consider the classList property of DOM elements. Its a much more flexible way of manipulating (adding/removing/etc) classes. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. Also, if this does answer your question why not mark this as the correct answer:)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply css when properties change you should use transitions, [link](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)  you can see it add the horizTranslate class class to box in the demo

Answer (score 0):

risingtiger was perfectly right! As soon as I made this change not only did it work , but if I rush the next animation it goes to it smoothly(I believe)

```
document.getElementById("Position"+i).className = "Pos"+positionsBefore[i]+"ForLeft";
```

Thank you very much wonderful people of the internet!! The solutions some other  programmers offered me were scary to say the least...